# Is there an analytics service out there that can provide analytics and stats for different users in an app?

Tags: web, google-analytics, analytics

I currently have a web app that allows users to create their own website through the platform, like `shopify`/`wordpress`/`squarespace`/`wix`. I also want to provide an **analytics dashboard** for these users to keep track of events and page views.

Are there any APIs for this? I took a look at various analytics services (google analytics, mixpanel, Adobe Analytics) but they all seem to be targeted at individual websites.

Or is the best way to keep create a custom solution storing page views and events in our own databases?

Any solution or ideas would be appreciated, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Localytics is a cloud-based analytics and marketing platform. This mobile analytics tool targets every customer from media, retail, travel, business and lifestyle. The retention feature is particularly interesting for users. This feature generates an analysis that pinpoints reasons for business problems, such as drop-offs, low conversion rates and reduced client retention.

Comment: Hi, does this support being able to build a custom analytics dashboard for users?